# Saving image from PictureBox after drawing to it

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have `PictureBox` with an `Image` , I use the `Paint` event to draw a line over it , but when I save the image, I get the image without the line been drawn

```
    private void PicBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, end, start);
        e.Graphics.Flush();
        e.Graphics.Save();
    } 

//and I save it like this
picBox.Image.Save("directory");
```

what am missing here?

Comment: Is the line drawn over it the program?

Comment: @kevin628 what do you mean? yes it's drawn and I can see it, but when I save it's just the image without the line...

Comment: Adding to @Idle's (almost correct) answer: Neither `e.Graphics.Flush()` nor `e.Graphics.Save()` should be there! Neither does what you probably think it does..

Answer (score 2):

You want the [DrawToBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picBox.ClientSize.Width, picBox.ClientSize.Height);
        picBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, picBox.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save("...fileName Here...");
    }
```

Comment: `  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picBox.Image.Width, picBox.Image.Height);
                    picBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, picBox.Image.Width, picBox.Image.Height));` it gives me an error , invalid parameter why is that!?

Comment: Please make that `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picBox.ClientSize.Width, picBox.ClientSize.Height);`!